# magento setup:upgrade error "deployment configuration is absent"

Tags: magento2, upgrade

When I try to upgrade Magento 2 `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` I get

I get

> [Magento\Setup\Exception]
>   Can't run this operation: deployment configuration is absent. Run 
>   'magento      setup:config:set --help' for options. setup:upgrade
>
> [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

How to fix it? Updating using the web updater gives the following errors:

[image]

I asked my hosting provider to fix them and they did install the right php version 5.6 and all extensions recommended by magento and created a [cron job](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_cron.html) but I still see the error.

---

**UPDATE:** *(from comments)*
`env.php` wasn't there, when I run `magento setup:config:set` I get this error:

> $ bin/magento setup:config:set
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]
>     Parameter validation failed

Comment: Check to see if `<magento install dir>/app/etc/env.php` is present. That is the deployment configuration. If it's absent, run the `magento setup:config:set` command again to create it.

Comment: @SteveJohnson env.php wasn't there, when I run `magento setup:config:set` i get this error http://pastebin.com/BDzxYGGU

Comment: The error indicates your Magento database user name and password don't match. I'm not sure it's a good idea to run your Magento database as `root`; have you seen our [MySQL setup instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/mysql.html#instgde-prereq-mysql-config)? Maybe try that and see if the command succeeds.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. It appeared that the `app/etc/env.php` was missing. This means that Magento was not yet installed. During Magento installation it will create this file, so:

- make sure `app/etc/` is writable for the magento user/webuser
- run `bin/magento setup:install ...params...`

In my case, some script that I made was not copying my `env.php` file into the `app/etc/` folder.

It is also possible that the file is there, but it is not readable for the Magento user/webuser.

Answer (score 90):

This error message is also shown if your `app/etc/config.php` is missing. If `app/etc/env.php` is present and you are still seeing this issue, check for `app/etc/config.php`. If it is not present, Magento can create it by running `bin/magento module:enable --all`. This will recreate the file. Then, try running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` again.

Comment: In my case this was the issue, `app/etc/env.php` was present but `app/etc/config.php` was not.

Comment: I have both app/etc/env.php and app/etc/config.php still having this error..

Comment: perfect answer!!! made my day +1 :)

Comment: This answer help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I am using Magento 2 by docker,

I had both `app/etc/env.php` and `app/etc/config.php` files. Also had `.htaccess` file in root folder and still had this error while running any command of magento:

```
Invalid configuration file: '/var/www/html/app/etc/env.php'
```

Then,

1. I killed all running containers with: `docker kill $(docker ps -q)`
2. Deleted all stopped containers with: `docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`
3. Deleted all images with: `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`
4. Removed all unused volumes with: `docker volume prune`

4th point is must.

And installed Docker Image for Magento 2 again. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to deploy your website.The first Check all folder in the .htaccess file is available after

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

and

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

or pub > static file checked not static folder so create static folder and `index.php` in Pub file. `index.php` not available so please copy your other project and paste

Answer (score 0):

Also check if your cache_dir is writable. I advise you to check your logfiles.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/178978)

Comment: @ManashviBirla, this is an answer. I had the same exact problem and it was because of the cache_dir not being writable...