# configuration for DB connection is absent

Tags: magento2, database, installation, composer

```
 bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
public_html/var/generation/Composer
public_html/var/generation/Magento
public_html/var/generation/Symfony
The directory 'public_html/var/di/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:

  [Magento\Setup\Exception]
  Can't run this operation: configuration for DB connection is absent.

setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]
```

I'm using Centos 6 64 bit server, Magento version 2.1.0, I thought this error was like [the previous error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122066/deployment-configuration-is-absent) so I asked my hosting provider to solve it by referring to that answer. They rerun the command and its output was:

```
We saved default values for these options: db-engine, db-model, db-init-statements.
```

And the issue wasn't solved. I am trying to install [nosto-magento2](https://github.com/Nosto/nosto-magento2) using composer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well it says that your di folder is not there in the error. delete the var folder and then run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and make sure it creates a di folder inside var. Then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Also check your database connection in `app/etc/env.php` and the permissions on that file.

Look at these lines in env.php and make sure they are correct:

```
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'your_dbname',
        'username' => 'your_user',
        'password' => 'your_pass',
        'active' => '1',
```

Also make sure your user has access to the database.

Update:
that means there still is an error with the di file. run these commands:

```
rm -rf var/di var/generation/ var/cache and var/page_cache
rm -rf pub/static/frontend pub/static/_requirejs/ pub/static/adminhtml
sudo chmod -R 777 var pub lib app/etc
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

As a sidenote, your env.php should look like this:

```
<?php
return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'login',
  ),
  'install' => 
  array (
    'date' => 'Mon, 14 Mar 2016 16:04:24 +0000',
  ),
  'crypt' => 
  array (
    'key' => 'cc1482148f935ef000f4b0c4bc',
  ),
  'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),
  'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'dbname' => 'db',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'resource' => 
  array (
    'default_setup' => 
    array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
  ),
  'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
  'cache_types' => 
  array (
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'full_page' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
  ),
);
```

Comment: the di error disappeared but the error is still there, and i don't have env, i have env.php containing some array, should i generate env?

Comment: @Lynob updated my answer

Comment: should i remove  the compiled and cache? http://pastebin.com/mnjM75fr

Comment: I don't think it will help you in this situation. It is clearly a db connection if you are still getting that error.

Comment: ok great now that error goes away so i must accept your answer however another error pops up and i was hoping you could help, `There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.` i chmod 777 -R var and pub and env.php, when i run `php bin/magento list` i get http://pastebin.com/5QaANQ4Z

Comment: should i delete var and cache and create di again? is it complicated, should i open another question?

Comment: my env.php http://pastebin.com/Cm64ZTGu

Comment: @Lynob yes, you are right, updated my answer

Comment: thanks so much, everything worked except the last command http://pastebin.com/T8411T6g

Comment: @Lynob then it means that you have an error in your modules. delete that nosto module and then try again. Also make sure that your php version is supported, either 5.6 or 7.0.6,  NOT: 7.0.0 or 7.05, 7.04 which are not supported.

Comment: yes i think i have error in my modules, I'll have to disable and try again, will do that in few days and let you know. Is it enough to run `-- module-disable` or should i remove it from composer.json? cause i have a big list of modules so i need a quick way to test which one is causing the issue