# Installation error on linux 2 aws?

Tags: error, installation, setup-upgrade, aws, linux

```
Updating modules:
Connection "default" is not defined
```

When I run Upgrade command I am getting this error?

Comment: Check connection settings to your database in app/etc/env.php

Answer (score 0):

This issues is you missed some connection i think you missed `app/etc/env.php` file

So, Please check the this link and may be help this link

**[configuration for DB connection is absent](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123015/configuration-for-db-connection-is-absent)**

And any query let me know...

Answer (score 0):

You need to review your `app/etc/env.php` to add `['db']['connection']['default']` part, ex:

```
<?php
return [
...
'db' => [
  'table_prefix' => '',
  'connection' => [
    'default' => [
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'dbname' => 'magento_db',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'admin123',
      'model' => 'mysql4',
      'engine' => 'innodb',
      'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
      'active' => '1'
    ]
  ]
]
...
];
```