# Invalid configuration file:app/etc/env.php in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, module, database

Disable module after run this command chown www-data -R /var/www/html

My env.php file empty.

php bin/magento c:f

Invalid configuration file: '/var/www/html/upgrademag/app/etc/env.php'

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Magento \ Framework \ Exception \ RuntimeException: Invalid configuration file: '/var/www/html/upgrademag/app/etc/env.php' in / var / www / html / upgrademag / vendor / magento / framework / App / DeploymentConfig / Reader.php: 118 Stack trace: # 0 /var/www/html/upgrademag/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php(140): Magento \ Framework \ App \ DeploymentConfig \ Reader-> load () # 1 /var/www/html/upgrademag/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php(70): Magento \ Framework \ App \ DeploymentConfig-> load () # 2 / var / www / html / upgrademag / vendor /magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(114): Magento \ Framework \ App \ DeploymentConfig-> get () # 3 /var/www/html/upgrademag/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(210 ): Magento \ Framework \ App \ ObjectManagerFactory-> create (Array) # 4 / var / www / html / upgrademag / vendor / magento / framework / App / Bootstrap.php (125): Magento \ Framework \ App \ Bootstrap -> __ construct (Object (Magento \ Framework \ App \ ObjectManagerFactory), '/ var / www / html / u ...', array) # 5 / var / www / html / upgrade / index.php (36): Magento \ Frame in/var/www/html/upgrademag/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig/Reader.php on line 118
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is also shown if your `app/etc/config.php` is missing. If `app/etc/env.php` is present and you are still seeing this issue, check for `app/etc/config.php`. If it is not present, Magento can create it by running `php bin/magento module:enable --all`. This will recreate the file. Then, try running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` again.

And More information this link :-

**[magento setup:upgrade error "deployment configuration is absent"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122066/magento-setupupgrade-error-deployment-configuration-is-absent)**

Comment: I have both env.php and config.php, but my env file is showing empty

Comment: you showing empty file because you disable the all module

Comment: I disabled only one module https://prnt.sc/rfmzgv

Comment: you enable the module and run php bin/magento s:up